# How can I list all EC2 instances using the Amazon .NET library?

Tags: c#, amazon-ec2, ip-address

I'm trying to programatically access all of my EC2 instances using the [.NET library](http://aws.amazon.com/developers/getting-started/net/).

How can I get a list of all instances, and fetch their individual IP address?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Listing Instances in AWS .NET SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871033/listing-instances-in-aws-net-sdk)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [AmazonEC2Client.DescribeInstances Method](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/M_Amazon_EC2_AmazonEC2Client_DescribeInstances.htm)

```
result = client.DescribeInstances();

foreach (var instance in result.Reservations[0].Instances) {
    privateIps.add(instance.PrivateIpAddress);
}
```

Comment: link is now dead

Answer (score 3):

In AWS and EC2 Speak, when you want to get a list of something, or find out more about it, it's a "Describe" call.

For example:

- [DescribeImages](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ApiReference-query-DescribeImages.html)
- [DescribeVolumes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ApiReference-query-DescribeVolumes.html)
- [DescribeSnapshots](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ApiReference-query-DescribeSnapshots.html)

... and the one you're specifically looking for:

- [DescribeInstances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ApiReference-query-DescribeInstances.html)

The DescribeInstances call will return you a data structure that has the IP Address for each instance. Note that this is a PAGED API, which means if you many instances (>1000) you'll need to keep calling it, providing the relevant page token, to get the complete list.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the sample code through which will get you the list of InstanceIDs:

```
_client = new AmazonEC2Client(awsAccessKeyId, awsSecretAccessKey, RegionEndpoint.USEast2);
        bool done = false;
        var InstanceIds = new List<string>();
        DescribeInstancesRequest request = new DescribeInstancesRequest();
        while (!done)
        {
            DescribeInstancesResponse response = await _client.DescribeInstancesAsync(request);

            foreach ( Reservation reservation in response.Reservations)
            {
                foreach (Instance instance in reservation.Instances)
                {
                    InstanceIds.Add(instance.InstanceId);
                }
            }

            request.NextToken= response.NextToken;

            if (response.NextToken == null)
            {
                done = true;
            }
        }
```

You can replace instance.InstanceId with instance.PublicIpAddress to get the list of IP addresses. Hope this helps!