# How to find the ip of an instance in EC2 using filter in C#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I have several EC2 instances and i wanted to find an ip addresses of those.
I was thinking to use `DescribeInstances` with `Filter`, but can't find any example how to apply `Filter`.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is already answered previously: [Listing Instances in AWS .NET SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871033/listing-instances-in-aws-net-sdk)

So, in addition to InstanceId and InstanceType which the example in the above link prints, you can also print

```
Console.WriteLine(runningInstance.PrivateIpAddress);
Console.WriteLine(runningInstance.PublicIpAddress);
```

If you need to add filter to the DescribeInstanceRequest then check  [DescribeInstanceRequest  With Filter](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/M_Amazon_EC2_Model_DescribeInstancesRequest_WithFilter.htm)

Example - How to set filter:

```
new DescribeInstancesRequest()
{
    Filter = new List<Filter>()
    {
        new Filter()
        {
            Name = "instance-id",
            Value = new List<String>()
            {
                "i-223c1a1b"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, the above filter will return the details of that particular instance with instance id: i-223c1a1b.

For more details about all the filters and their names, see [DescribeInstances Filters](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html)

Comment: i took part where you apply a filter. Thanks